# Preventing too many connections in MySql when inserting tens of thousands of records

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, scrapy

I am having issues with MySQL in that I constantly get a "database has too many connections error" when inserting tens of thousands of records. I am using Python and Scrapy to scrape webpages and insert the information into MySQL. Here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb     

# connect to the MySQL server
self.CONN = MySQLdb.connect(host=SQL_HOST,
    user=SQL_USER,
    passwd=SQL_PASSWD,
    db=SQL_DB,
    charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

cursor = self.CONN.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, license, address, name, city, state, zip_code, country) \
          SELECT uuid(), '" + item['license_num'] + "', '" + item['address'] + "', '" + item['name'] + "', '" + item['city']+ "', '" + item['state'] + "', '" + item['city'] + "', '" + item['state'] + "', '" + item['zip_code'] + "', '" + item['country'] FROM (SELECT 1) t \
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE license='" + item['license_num'] + "');"

if cursor.execute(sql):
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print results
    print 'ADDED BUSINESS: ' + item['name']
    print json.dumps(dict(item), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    self.CONN.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

I thought it might be memory issues but I checked:

```
[root@s18573288 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096       1896       2199        106          0       1370
-/+ buffers/cache:        525       3570
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Doesn't seem to be a memory issue. Only 6% of my disk space is being utilized. I don't want to restart MySQL as it could corrupt my data. I am hoping that it will recover if I just let it run. So my question is how can improve the sql below to prevent too many connections?

Comment: Are you doing a loop anywhere?

Comment: Yes, everytime a Scrapy Item is scraped this code is called.

Comment: Are you creating too many objects that have a connection to mysql ? closing the cursor will not close the connection to mysql. Ideally you should have just one object in the process to connect to mysql database. If you are running the process under Linux, you may use "lsof" commands to check number of open sockets or connections from the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to ensure that the cursor is closed every time you call the code.
this code may help

```
import MySQLdb     

# connect to the MySQL server
self.CONN = MySQLdb.connect(host=SQL_HOST,
    user=SQL_USER,
    passwd=SQL_PASSWD,
    db=SQL_DB,
    charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

cursor = self.CONN.cursor()

sql = """\
INSERT INTO myTable (id, license, address, name, city, state, zip_code, country) \
SELECT uuid(), \
'" + item['license_num'] + "', \
'" + item['address'] + "', \
'" + item['name'] + "', \
'" + item['city']+ "', \
'" + item['state'] + "', \
'" + item['city'] + "', \
'" + item['state'] + "', \
'" + item['zip_code'] + "', \
'" + item['country'] \
FROM (SELECT 1) t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE license='" + item['license_num'] + "');
"""

try:
    cursor.execute(sql):
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print results
    print 'ADDED BUSINESS: ' + item['name']
    print json.dumps(dict(item), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    self.CONN.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Okay, so when I implement it like you suggest I get “Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now” (2014) exception

Comment: Should I opening a new connection for every insert?

Answer (score 1):

try to close MySQL connection in the end of the script

```
finally:
    cursor.close() 
    self.CONN.close()  # close connection
```